# How do I disable TLS Session Tickets in Chrome?

Tags: encryption, tls, cryptography

According to [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html) SSL Session tickets are enabled by default. These are the [weakest link in TLS](https://blog.filippo.io/we-need-to-talk-about-session-tickets/), how do I disable them? I'm using the latest stable.